# One tab bar controller item should be hidden in iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing an app in which I am using tab bar controller. When the app is opened it should display only one tab bar item "Restaurants" and when i select some food item from the menu of any restaurant, then another tab bar viewcontroller called items should be displayed. Please help me how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

1. Create your application as you want and make sure when you add `TabBarController`, there should be only one tab item (Delete other item which is by default added when you add tabbarcontroller)
2. Create new subclass of `UITabBarController`
3. Assign class of all your controller from storyboard as well as assign specific storyboard identifier
4. Declare global property of type `BOOL` (in user defaults or where you want to maintain) I have added in `AppDelegate.h`

   ```
   @property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isAddNew;
   ```
5. Now from where you want to add (Show) new tab in tabor, add code, My Code is :

   ```
   - (IBAction)addNewTab:(id)sender
   {
       AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
       appDelegate.isAddNew = TRUE;
       [self.tabBarController viewDidLoad];
   }
   ```
6. Then go to your custom tabbarcontroller (which is created in step 2 -> subclass of `UITabBarController`), My class is `.h`

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface TabViewController : UITabBarController

   @end
   ```

And `.m` is

```
#import "TabViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "ViewController3.h"

@interface TabViewController ()
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
@end

@implementation TabViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (appDelegate.isAddNew == TRUE)
    {
        ViewController2 *view2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
        //ViewController3 *view3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController3"];

        NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [self.viewControllers mutableCopy];   //  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [tabViewControllers addObject:view2];
        //[tabViewControllers addObject:view3];

        [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];

        //can't set this until after its added to the tab bar

        // ------ First way ------
        view2.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectimg.png"] tag:1];

        // ------ Second way ------
        view2.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectimg"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectimg.png"]];

        // ------ Third way ------
        view2.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
        view2.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectimg.png”]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        view2.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectimg.png”]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
        view2.tabBarItem.title = @"Second";

        //view3.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Third" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"third.png"] tag:2];

        [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:self];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```